# Binary Search Tree with Forms

Tags: c#, forms, user-interface, binary-search-tree

I am working on an assignment and I need to implement a Binary Search Tree with Forms. Now, I know how to create a BST with not much problems, But to use it with forms and create a GUI is confusing to me.

So, what I would like to ask is how do I implement a BST to a form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're approaching this with the mindset that the UI and the Binary Tree have to be intertwined so closely that you'll need to modify your BST class. Instead, think of it like this.

Your BST class will take an input. Where you get this input from doesn't, and shouldn't matter, to your BST. So you'd create an instance of your tree, as normal, and pass in the input from a TextBox for example. So the user clicks a button (you handle the button click event). Within this event, you read the TextBox data and then send that to your BST class. The class will return values which you now have in a collection, for example.

The final step is to work with that collection. As a basic example, you could bind that collection a ListBox so after your method returns the values, you set the `ItemsSource` property of the ListBox to the collection that was returned.

The idea is that you need to think of your BST class being logically separate from your UI. This makes it easier to break down what you want to achieve into smaller steps.

Answer (score 0):

What effort did you put in learning windows forms so far? Your question is to general.
If it's your first contact with winforms, you could [start on msdna](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492171.aspx) - those are pretty interesting examples, that'll introduce you the basics.